# Laravel 5 not loading images in subfolder

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for the solution of an error in my laravel 5 project. I have my project in public_html folder, so my project is working on good except the images that I have in a subfolder.

This is my project structure:

- root

  - laravel
  - public_html

    - index.php
    - images

      - users

        - default.jpg

I've got a main template called workspace.blade.php, in script tag I've got a js variable to refer my project folder image:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Url = '{{ URL::asset('/'). Lang::getLocale() }}/';
        var resourcesUrl = Url + 'resources/';
        var imagesUrl = '{{ URL::asset('images') }}';
        var jsUrl = '{{ URL::asset('js/') }}';
    </script>
```

So in a EJS Javascript template I am printing my image:

```
<img src="<%= imagesUrl + '/users/default.jpg' %>">
```

But the browser console always show me the following error:

```
GET http://mydomain.com.co/users/default.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

If I try to load an image from "images/" folder, it works good, but If I try to load an image inside of subfolder from images like "images/users/" it doesn't work anymore.

I've printed the url directly, but it happens nothing. The wrong is laravel redirects the url to route in route collection and it throws an error of routing.

I don't know if I must modify my .htaccess file, but this is it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks for help me!

Comment: This path related issue. The URL to the image is wrong as you are trying to load and image from a route that doesn't exist

Comment: Also note that you can not access resources folder from public folder. An option is to move your images to public folder or you can you a route to load image from resource folder by using an image package like intervention image to dynamically generate the image

Comment: Thanks Digitlimit. The route exists. It simply not working in production so everything is working fine in development. My images are not in resources folder because my laravel installation is in the root folder. The public folder is in the public_html folder of my server.

Comment: If it works in development server then is probably htacess issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `images`

```
<img src="<%= imagesUrl + '/users/default.jpg' %>">
```

Should be

```
 <img src="<%= imagesUrl + '/images/users/default.jpg' %>">
```

Comment: When I inspect the DOM I see the right route, so my laravel application always looks for a route in routes.php (RouteCollection), why the main folder images/ is loaded well?

Comment: @Brian can you see your image in this URL `http://mydomain.com.co/images/users/default.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the error. Just my "images/users" folder and it's files inside don't have the right permissions. It had 640 permissions, so I've changed that for 644.